# Java 8 SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong Sources

Tags: java, javadoc, java-8, prng

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstanceStrong--) for `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` says that it returns a pRNG instance from the securerandom.strongAlgorithms java.security.Security property.

Is there Java documentation that lists these properties by platform?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently not, you should expect such information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecureRandom), but it just lists the algorithms without splitting them up per OS.

You can however print the list from your local JRE with

`java.security.Security.getProperty( "securerandom.strongAlgorithms" )`

For example, my Windows 7 machine returns the algorithms:

```
Windows-PRNG:SunMSCAPI
SHA1PRNG:SUN
```

While a Linux platform will return

```
NativePRNGBlocking:SUN
```

which will normally result in random values read from `/dev/random` as per documentation.